# Python error: global declared variable is not declared in the global scope

Tags: python, variables, global-variables

I am quite new to python, and I tried to make a simple GUI program. 
But, I got into a "problem", exactly a warning, that says: 
'm' is not defined in the global scope (Python(variable-not-defined-globally)).

I know that you need to declare a var global inside a function if you want to access it outside that function scope. Although I don't use this new created variable outside the function, if I don't declare it global, my program only shows the GUI for a fraction of a second, then it closes it.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget

def show():
    global m
    m = QWidget()
    m.setWindowTitle("Testing this app")
    m.show()

MYAPP = QApplication(sys.argv)
show()
MYAPP.exec_()
```

Could you explain why is this happening? Thanks in advance!

Comment: this is only a editor warning. You can ignore it. But you should not use global variables.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`global` tells python to look for a variable with this name in the global namespace and include it in the local namespace. This means it must exist in the global namespace first.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget

m = None  # variable must exist in global namespace first

def show():
    global m  # this creates a local m that is linked to the global m
    m = QWidget()
    m.setWindowTitle("Testing this app")
    m.show()

MYAPP = QApplication(sys.argv)
show()
MYAPP.exec_()
```

Comment: that is not what the global statement does. And it absolutely is not required to exist in the global namespace first. This answer is totally wrong, although, it does fix the linter warning. a `global` statement is basically a directive *to the compiler* that *assignment statements* to a variable should modify a *global* instead of *local* variable. basically, it means "Use a STORE_GLOBAL opcode instead of a STORE_FAST opcode" if you want to get into the nitty gritty of it

Comment: "# this creates a local m that is linked to the global m" no, no it doesn't.

Comment: By "must" I simply meant "in order to achieve the requested-for behavior" which is for m not to get freed as soon as the function returned.

Comment: look, "`global` tells python to look for a variable with this name in the global namespace and include it in the local namespace. " is a completely incorrect description of what the `global` statement does. Fundamentally, that is my gripe. All a global statement does is *tell the compiler that assignments should happen to a global rather than a local variable*.

Comment: And furthermore, it **doesn't** mean that it has to exist in the global namespace first. And `m` won't get "freed" as soon as the function returns if you omit `m = None`

Answer (score 0):

You should also declare `m` in the global scope before it is used by `show()`. You can do this by setting `m=None` right before you call `show()`.